# JpaRepository (Neo4j) sorting on multiple ambiguous columns?

Tags: java, jpa, neo4j, spring-data-jpa

This is specific to Neo4jRepository, but it may apply to others...

I have 2 entities, Movie and Person. I want to sort by Movie.title then Person.name, but the query comes back as, so its sticking the order by clause all on the first object:

MATCH (n:`Movie`) WITH n ORDER BY n.`title`,n.`name` RETURN n,[ [ (n)<-[r_d1:`DIRECTED`]-(p1:`Person`) | [ r_d1, p1 ] ], [ (n)<-[r_a1:`ACTED_IN`]-(p1:`Person`) | [ r_a1, p1 ] ], [ (n)<-[r_p1:`PRODUCED`]-(p1:`Person`) | [ r_p1, p1 ] ] ], ID(n) with params {}

```
return ImmutableList.copyOf(this.movieRepository.findAll(Sort.by(Order.asc("title"),
                                                                 Order.asc("name"))));
```

Do I need to specify a custom query? Or is there a built in way to specify what the order by applies to?

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to write a custom query.

The `find` methods on repositories apply the sort to properties of the domain object belonging to the repository- in this case, a Movie.